# Autocad, Inventor API access with Clojure

Tags: clojure, autocad, autodesk-inventor

Has anybody had any experience accessing the Autocad or Inventor API with Clojure?

Comment: I don't like it when people tell me how to ask questions, but I'm going to do it here. Ask a more specific question, or ask perhaps for an example "hello world" equivalent for those API's, and somebody might be able to help you get going.

Comment: Sorry I can't be specific, because if I would have had an example of accesing the api or have seen one I would'n have posted the question to begin with. Thank you anyway.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you can access autocad through Java, then you can get to it from Clojure. I found this SO question on that matter. (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/856973/interfacing-autocad-with-java) Basically they've built a JNI bridge to the autocad API. Once you do that then you can access that through Clojure. It sounds like a non-trivial undertaking though to say the least.

I'm pretty old, and the last time I checked (*cough* 20+ years ago *cough*), Autocad was extensible via Autolisp. If that's still true, then would you really want to bolt on Clojure? Just curious.

Comment: Thanks again Bill. Yes I had read those postings. I also saw possible solution with Java-Com bridge products at http://www.javain.com/javain/index.jsp. There is also a what could be a valid project on Java4Autocad at http://java4autocad.sourceforge.net/. I am probably much older than you are. Have worked with AutoLisp for 20 years. Because of previous Lisp experience I am doing the transition to Clojure working on a project to externally create data to apply on CAD objects Autocad, also 3D systems as Inventor, SolidWorks, Catia, etc... Will be logical to write that end part also in Clojure.

Comment: Very interesting. That makes a lot of sense. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, AutoDesk exposes API for their products in .net environment. There is a paralel clojure implementation in Microsoft clr (.net environmet).

https://github.com/richhickey/clojure-clr

I think this would be a better way to aproach Autocad Scripting.

Comment: this is incorrect. Autocad has interface with multiple languages. https://help.autodesk.com/view/OARX/2023/ENU. C++ (OARX), VBA (ACTIVEX), AutoList (DCL). Java script. a Clojure/Java link would probably be the more natural path.